# How to append string in the middle of a pre-existing csv line?

Tags: python, string, list, append

I am fairly new to working with python and finally encountered a problem I cannot circumvent. I will make this fairly simple.

I have a csv file with many lines that looks like this once I create a list variable:

```
['1\t10000\t11000\tabcdef\t1\t+\t10000\t11000\t"0,0,0"\t1\t1000\t0\n']
```

I want to add 2 new string variables after the final \t0 before the \n. Its important to indicate I still want the \t before str1 and str2. So the output I desire should look like this:

```
['1\t10000\t11000\tabcdef\t1\t+\t10000\t11000\t"0,0,0"\t1\t1000\t0\tstr1\tstr2n']
```

Thanks for your help!

```
str1 = hello
str2 = world
line = ['1\t10000\t11000\tabcdef\t1\t+\t10000\t11000\t"0,0,0"\t1\t1000\t0\n']
line.append(('\t') + str1 + ('\t') + str2)
print(line)
```

Current output:

```
['1\t10000\t11000\tabcdef\t1\t+\t10000\t11000\t"0,0,0"\t1\t1000\t0\n', '\tstr1\tstr2']
```

Comment: work with the single string inside `line`. Note, having a list with just a single item in it doesn't really make sense

Comment: My code is really big and the list helps when I'm working with different lines, its just this part that's hindering my work.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how a list with a single string really helps, and is better than a list with separate strings for each field.

Comment: Your desired output ends with `\tstr2n`. Is that `n` supposed to be `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The append method adds the input to the list you use it on.
Since line is a list, you are getting a new entry into your list.

If you want to keep your string inside the list, you need to access the 0th index of the list to change the string:

```
line[0]
```

Once you have the string you need to separate it into two and add your new strings:

```
line[0] = line[0][:-2] + newinput + line[0][-2:]
```

Note the -2 separated because you want to separate the last two characters of your string: `\n`

Answer (score 0):

`append()` is for adding an element to a list. To add to a string, use `+=` on the variable that contains the string, which is `line[0]`.

```
line[0] += f'\t{str1}\t{str2}'
```

That said, it's strange that you have the entire line as a single element of the list, rather than parsing the CSV row into a list of fields, using `\t` as the field delimiter.

Comment: your point is fair. In either case, how to I target a position thats within the string and not at the end?

Comment: @user20330606 you really shouldn't be working with strings like this to begin with. You should be working with actual container types like `list` objects, and using the `csv` module to parse/write your csv files

Comment: @user20330606 Use `split()` to split the string into a list, `insert()` to insert in the appropriate place in the list, then `join()` to convert that back to a string.